# How to convert string to conditional expression in PHP?

Tags: php, eval, conditional-statements

I have string like this,

```
$condition = "if($test == '1')";
```

I want to convert it to a conditional expression without using `eval()`.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know other method to evaluate code, but depend on your need, you should be able to have what you are expected with another way (switch, etc..). Can you give us more explanations about the purpose ..?

Comment: just use $condition = ($test == '1'); the result of the expression will be assigned to $condition...

Comment: `EVIL`, oh I mean `EVAL()`, is your best bet

Comment: why not to use eval()?

Comment: For example i have associative array,
$adata = array('name' => 'John', 'age' => 21);

i have a function that convert that to a string so the output will be like this,

$condition = "if($name == 'John' && $age == 21);";

and i want $condition to be converted into a regular conditional expression.

Comment: they said that eval() is dangerous so that's why im searching for other way to do that.

Comment: Is your use case one where there's absolutely no other way to get the parameters for the conditional than accepting a whole string? If it's user-defined, could you prompt them separately for the two arguments and then the preferred combinator?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at <kbd>[**`$functionName()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)</kbd> or <kbd>[**`call_user_func($functionName)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)</kbd>

<kbd>[**`More clarification.`**](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/17/php_foundations.html?page=2)</kbd>